# test plan is not getting executed while using 1 thread for one loop and using throughput controllers inside the thread group

Tags: testing, jmeter, throughput

i have a test plan in which 
[image]

[image]

distribution of throughput controllers is

```js
post and get 1 => 10%
post and get 2 => 40%
post and get 3 => 25%
post => 25%
```

if i run the test plan with loopcount = forever then it is working fine with single thread or multiple theads

but if i run the test plan with loopcount = 1 and threads = 1 it is not even starting the test.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1 thread to 1 loop means only 1 execution with 1 thread where you want that to split the execution between different percentage. This is not possible. But, loop is forever, 1 thread can run many iteration and execution the request based on the defined percentage. This is possible.

So, options are loop forever or increase number of threads. In your case minimum 6 thread will work for 1 iteration. Increase thread for multiple execution based on percentage.

Hope this helps.